# I dont understand exterior derivatives of differential forms

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-derivative

The exterior derivative of a zero-form is a one-form

$ df =
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} e^{x}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} e^{y}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} e^{z} = 
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz
$

The exterior derivative of a one-form is a two-form

$dF = \left( 
  \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} 
- \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} 
\right) \mathbf{e^{xy}} +
\left( 
  \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z} - 
  \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} 
\right) 
\mathbf{e^{zx}} + 
\left( 
  \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} - 
  \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z} 
\right) 
\mathbf{e^{yz}}$

df is the total derivative of f so it makes perfect sense to call it df.

But dF is not the total derivative of F. So why call it dF?

Comment: What are you defining as the "total differential"

Comment: Total derivative

Comment: Can you not use $e^x$ for the basis?

Comment: The total derivative in genetal will be denoted $DF$ or $JF$, where J stands for Jacobian

Comment: I figured it was some form of Jacobian. I have never heard of DF before.

Comment: The exterior derivative is an operator which plays with the exterior algebra structure $\Lambda T^*M$, and for whatever reason people chose to adopt the notation $d$.

Comment: But your $F$ (not my choice of notation) is a $1$-form, not a function. Who are you to say what “total derivative” should now mean or not mean?